# How to re-order accounts in Mail.app (El Capitan)

Tags: mail.app, macos, accounts

Since I upgraded to El Capitan the Mail.app was upgraded also (to version 9.2) and the ability to re-order accounts was disappeared.
Now I cannot move accounts in the preferences.
[image: preferences]

Who knows is there any configuration plist to resolve this issue manually?

Comment: I thought I had found such a thing at `~/Library/Mail/V2/MailData/Accounts.plist`…except that the order there was not the order of the accounts in Mail. ¯\ _(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

If you delete the accounts from Mail.app and then add them back in the order you want them to be in, it will save the order. There is currently no way to manually change the order after the accounts have been created within Mail.

Comment: But you can in the Mail.app move the order of the accounts around - e.g. under the inbox section.

Comment: But that doesn’t change the order of the accounts that you see when you right-click on a message and select Move To.